# Disable mobile theme on magento 1.5

Tags: magento, mobile, themes

Hello I have a website running on magento 1.5 . It's having separate theme for all mobile devices. Need to disable this completely so that only desktop view is displayed on mobile devices also...
Please help...

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin -> system -> configuration -> general -> design. You should see some expression below package name, delete them and you should be good to go. Don't forget to re-fresh all caches.